# what is the purpose of offset in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector {
    float x, y, z;
};

int main() {
    
    size_t offset = (long)&((Vector*)nullptr)->x;
    std::cout << offset << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)offsetof(struct Vector,y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (int)offsetof(struct Vector,z) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What does offset of a struct member exactly means and what is its purpose?
I have tried with some online resources and I could get it.Off
**Explain how offset exaclty works with this code!**

Comment: Yes exaclty, and where can we use them?

Comment: There is no "purpose" of this `offset` in C++. This was a technique in C of accomplishing tasks that can be done in more civilized ways in C++. Occasionally its use can be found in a library that implements some sort of a low-level interface with a low-level operating system API. But in terms of C++, this can be happily forgotten, and we can move to bigger and better things.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: In C++, some of the tricks that use `offsetof` can be achieved using pointer-to-member instead which is type-safe.  Here's a toy example, but is by no means a recommended use for this: https://godbolt.org/z/YYG45voMW -- in fact, if you don't absolutely encounter a need for it, it's best to forget that you know about it.  I come across a legit need for this maybe once every few years.

Comment: Now that we've swept `offsetof` under the rug, let me tell you about `goto`...

Comment: @Eljay: Well, `offsetof` at least is well-defined C++.  But the `&((Vector*)nullptr)->x` hack is definitely not.

Comment: A compiler's implementation may implement `offsetof` macro exactly what the `offset` is doing.  But that's the compiler's implementation, which has insider knowledge that such **undefined behavior** (as per the C++ standard) is well-defined behavior by the compiler.  That is not license to rely on that behavior to be portable.